# Recording ImageMagick histogram data into Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: python, excel, imagemagick

I've gotten some code thrown together that will go through a folder, open all images with a certain ending, and create a histogram of them with ImageMagick. What I can't do (and maybe this is a conceptualization issue as I'm still fairly new to this), is figure out how to record that into a spreadsheet, ideally with the filename attached. PyXl seems to work with Pandas and Numpy, but I can't figure out the path to take this output and record it.

Is there a solution to take the histogram output and record it in a spreadsheet?

Edit: Adding my code thus far. Operating in Windows 10 Pro, using VSCode.

```py
#import necessary packages
import os
import wand
import OpenPyXl

#define color library
magick xc:AliceBlue xc:AntiqueWhite xc:aquamarine xc:brown xc:azure xc:beige xc:bisque xc:black xc:BlanchedAlmond xc:blue xc:BlueViolet xc:chocolate4 xc:firebrick4 xc:burlywood xc:cadet blue xc:chartreuse xc:chocolate xc:tan4 xc:coral xc:CornflowerBlue xc:cornsilk xc:crimson xc:blue4 xc:cyan4 xc:DarkGoldenrod xc:DarkGreen xc:DarkGray xc:DarkKhaki xc:DarkMagenta xc:DarkOliveGreen xc:DarkOrange xc:DarkOrchid xc:DarkRed xc:DarkSalmon xc:DarkSeaGreen xc:DarkSlateBlue xc:DarkSlateGray xc:DarkTurquoise xc:DarkViolet xc:DeepPink xc:DeepSkyBlue xc:DimGray xc:DodgerBlue xc:firebrick xc:FloralWhite xc:ForestGreen xc:fuchsia xc:gainsboro xc:GhostWhite xc:gold xc:goldenrod xc:fractal xc:green xc:GreenYellow xc:honeydew xc:HotPink xc:IndianRed xc:indigo xc:ivory xc:khaki xc:lavender xc:LavenderBlush xc:LawnGreen xc:LemonChiffon xc:LightBlue xc:LightCoral xc:LightCyan xc:LightGoldenrodYellow xc:LightGray xc:LightGreen xc:LightPink xc:LightSalmon xc:LightSeaGreen xc:LightSkyBlue xc:LightSlateGray xc:LightSteelBlue xc:LightYellow xc:green1 xc:LimeGreen xc:linen xc:maroon xc:aquamarine3 xc:blue3 xc:MediumOrchid xc:MediumPurple xc:MediumSeaGreen xc:MediumSlateBlue xc:MediumSpringGreen xc:MediumTurquoise xc:MediumVioletRed xc:MidnightBlue xc:MintCream xc:MistyRose xc:moccasin xc:NavajoWhite xc:navy xc:OldLace xc:olive xc:OliveDrab xc:orange xc:OrangeRed xc:orchid xc:PaleGoldenrod xc:PaleGreen xc:PaleTurquoise xc:PaleVioletRed xc:PapayaWhip xc:PeachPuff xc:peru xc:pink xc:plum xc:PowderBlue xc:purple xc:red xc:RosyBrown xc:RoyalBlue xc:chocolate4 xc:salmon xc:SandyBrown xc:SeaGreen xc:seashell xc:sienna xc:silver xc:SkyBlue xc:SlateBlue xc:SlateGray xc:snow xc:SpringGreen xc:SteelBlue xc:tan xc:teal xc:thistle xc:tomato xc:turquoise xc:violet xc:wheat xc:gray100 xc:gray96 xc:yellow xc:OliveDrab3

#define photo folder
directory = 'C:\Users\tr9800a\Downloads\Bilder'

#find files ending in -2 and remap them with defined colors
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith("-2.jpg"):
        magick filename +dither -remap map.jpg result.jpg
        magick identify -verbose result.jpg | grep -A9 Histogram

#write results to spreadsheet
        (this is where I've gotten stuck)
        continue
    else:
```

I fully accept I likely made some major errors. Again, rookie here.

There are about 13000 photos to address, and the hope is to capture the four most frequent color values from each image. I was using the Magick remapping as a shortcut to convert slight variations in color into one of the core 140 colors we have in our system.

The most ideal output would be:

Image ID, Most frequent Hex Code, Pixel count, 2nd most frequent Hex Code, Pixel count, 3rd Hex Code, Pixel count, 4th Hex Code, Pixel count

Comment: If you add your code we'll have a much better idea what the extension is, whether your files have transparency or not, what OS you are using, how many files you have, how the histogram is supposed to look...

Comment: I added some code and those details.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Please say more about how a line in the spreadsheet should look. In the meantime, note you can run a command more like this: `magick IMAGE.JPG +dither -remap PALETTE.PNG -format %c histogram:info:` and get it done in a single invocation.

Comment: Oh cool, that actually makes a lot of sense. 

As for the output, the ideal scenario is the Image ID, then the four most frequent color Hex Codes and their pixel count so I can discriminate for use.

Comment: Note sure what your *"colour library"* piece of code is, but would suggest you use a loss-less PNG or GIF format for it rather than a lossy JPEG. And you can make the (tiny) palette file for remapping with a command like `magick xc:AliceBlue xc:AntiqueWhite xc:aquamarine ... +append palette.gif`

Comment: Also not sure I would really want to write code to generate an Excel file and introduce that as a further dependency - but that may just be a personal thing. I would probably write a simple CSV and import it into Excel.

Comment: I assume you have worked out you need `subprocess.run()` for calling the **ImageMagick** stuff https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Generating a CSV would be great by me. I agree it sounds less chaotic.

As for the subprocess, that makes sense. I hadn't tried to knit these processes together yet but knew I was forgetting something. This has me feeling thoroughly ignorant/amateur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reflection, I think I would probably do it with **PIL**, **wand** or **OpenCV** rather than parse the output of **ImageMagick** which is a bit ugly and error-prone. I have not worked out a full answer but these ideas might get you started:

---

Rather than use a lossy JPEG for your palette of colours, I would suggest you use a loss-less PNG or GIF format. You can make the (tiny) palette file for remapping with a command like:

```
magick xc:AliceBlue xc:AntiqueWhite xc:aquamarine ... +append palette.gif
```

[image]

and then use:

```
magick INPUT.JPG +dither -remap palette.gif ...
```

---

You can get just the histogram in a single invocation of **ImageMagick** rather than two with a command like:

```
magick IMAGE.JPG +dither -remap PALETTE.PNG -format %c histogram:info
```

**Sample Output**

```
307574: (0,0,0) #000000 black
11896: (170,0,0) #AA0000 srgb(170,0,0)
```

---

You can parse **ImageMagick** histogram output like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re, subprocess

# Empty list of colours
colours = []

# Get histogram from IM
res = subprocess.run(["magick","QcDsS.jpg","-remap", "palette.gif", "-format","%c","histogram:info:"], capture_output=True)

# Process IM result
for line in res.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
    # Find count and hex colour with regex
    match = re.match(r'\s*(\d+)[^#]*(\S+).*',line)
    count = int(match.groups()[0])
    hex   = match.groups()[1]
    print(count,hex)
    colours.append((count,hex))

s = sorted(colours,reverse=True)
print('Sorted\n',s)
```

**Sample Output**

```
297391 #000000
2389 #555555
6898 #AA0000
12 #AA00AA
30 #AA5500
480 #FF5555
Sorted
 [(297391, '#000000'), (6898, '#AA0000'), (2389, '#555555'), (480, '#FF5555'), (30, '#AA5500'), (12, '#AA00AA')]
```

Comment: A quick question: I've been playing with different options on your solution, and it works great in a lot of ways. There's one thing I can't figure out: how do I point magick at the active file? 

I'm iterating through thousands of photos in the server,but I can't find a way to make it process whatever file is assigned to filename, for example.

Any pointers?

Comment: @ mark-setchell That said, I've also tried solutions with PIL and OpenCV but I run into two issues that I've been beating my head against the wall trying to resolve. 

I'm unclear in OpenCV how to quantize to a custom palette, it seems like you can only quantize to a set number of colors. Additionally, I cannot figure out how to count and sort tuples within a numpy array, as is produced by the PIL quantization. 

I've even explored funky maneuvers like quantizing with PIL, saving to an image, and using cv2 to produce a list of BGR values which I converted to RGB, but, again, numpy array.